# Uploading An Image With Google Apps Script To A GSheet - Passing Values To And From HTML Service Modal Dialog

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications, form-submit

I'm trying to trigger a file upload off of a Google Sheet, taking the uploaded file, add it to a Google Drive folder, and then return the URL of the uploaded file and place it in a cell on the Sheet. I'm currently triggering the file upload by using a checkbox. Once you set the checkbox to `TRUE`, it'll pop up a dialog box with a file upload input field. This is triggered by an installed `onEdit` function. Also, info on the row in the sheet will be used to name the newly uploaded file. This info will be input manually on the sheet.

I get to the `showModalDialog` line, and the dialog box comes up just fine, but I can't figure out how to pass variables from the original function to the HTML service and then back again (with the file) to upload to Drive, set the name, and put the URL back on the sheet.

Here's the first function in **Code.gs**, receiving values from the `onEdit` function:

```
function addFile(ss,ui,row,total) { \\Triggered if edited cell is in column 25 & value is TRUE
  Logger.log('add file function');
  var name = ss.getRange(row,1).getDisplayValue();
  var date = ss.getRange(row,3).getDisplayValue();
  var filename = 'Row ' + row + ' - ' + name + ' - ' + date + ' - ' + total;
  var htmlTemp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index');
  htmlTemp.fName = filename;
  htmlTemp.position = row;
  var html = htmlTemp.evaluate().setHeight(76).setWidth(415);
  ui.showModalDialog(html, 'Upload');
  Logger.log('end of add file function');
}
```

And here's what's in **Index.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_center">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  <form>
    Please upload image below.<br /><br />
    <input type="file" name="upload" id="file" accept="image/*,.pdf" />
    <input type="button" value="Submit" class="action" onclick="formData(this.parentNode)" />
    <input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />
  </form>
  <script>
    function formData(obj){
      var newFileName = <? fName ?>;
      var rowNum = <? position ?>;

  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(closeIt).upload(obj,newFileName,rowNum);
    }
    function closeIt(e){
      console.log(e);
      google.script.host.close();
    };
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's the return function on **Code.gs**:

```
function upload(obj,newFileName,rowNum) {
  Logger.log('upload function');
  var upFile = DriveApp.getFolderById('[folderid]').createFile(obj).setName(newFileName);
  var fileUrl = upFile.getUrl();
  Logger.log(fileUrl);
  var urlCell = SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName('sheet name').getRange(rowNum,26);
  urlCell.setValue('=HYPERLINK("' + fileUrl + '","View image")');
}
```

Running this code, the dialog box comes up just fine, and I'm able to select a file for upload. However, clicking the Submit button does nothing, and the box stays up until I X it out or hit the Cancel button. The logs only get so far as 'end of add file function' and never gets to the `upload` function. Should the `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler` line close the dialog box, or is something else needed to confirm / get the file and close the box?

I've been searching online and have found a number of posts relating to this, but none seem to address this specific issue. This is also pretty much a frankenstein of code I've cobbled together from those posts, so it's possible there's just something that doesn't belong in there and if that is the case I do apologize. Any help would be appreciated; thanks!

[Edit: the submit button wasn't opening a separate tab because I was using `<input type="button">` instead of `<button>`.]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Script - Sidebar button keeps opening a new tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53825069/google-script-sidebar-button-keeps-opening-a-new-tab)

Comment: Can you do  console.log(e) to the variables inside formData() function? And upload a screenshot of "Developer tools" -> "console", maybe there's and error when trying to execute formData(obj)

Comment: The upload never returns anything so the dialog never get's closed. But using onEdit() simple trigger here is not wise since simple it has to finish in 30 seconds and you have a modal dialog and a file upload which are both likely to take a while.

Comment: @TheMaster Since I'm using `<input type="button" ...` I don't think it's that issue. I changed it to `<button type="button" ... >Submit</button>` but it's still exhibiting the same behavior. The Submit is just the value in my example, and not the type of button. Thanks for the suggestion, though!

Comment: @AndresDuarte There are no logs that show up on the Apps Script Dashboard for any of these attempts. I added some new `console.log` lines in `formData` and `closeIt` like you suggested, but nothing comes through. I even tried just putting in some text instead of capturing `e` or another variable and still no dice. It just lists ["No logs are available for this execution."](https://i.imgur.com/p6KMZ6s.png) So it looks like it may not even be triggering those functions in the HTML file.

Comment: @Cooper I'm actually using an installable trigger, and the on Edit function is named something different, `onACellEdit`. Is that 30 second limit still enforced on installable triggers?

Comment: Html logs are available in the browser. There's a console in the browser. That's what Andres is referring to.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53803325/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54214979 `google.script.run.upload` should only pass `obj`

Comment: @TheMaster gotcha. And I think those two questions you linked do relate to this situation, though I didn't realize it because I wasn't really using the correct terms / keywords. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation [1] in the “Parameters and return values” part,
if you’re going to send the form object as a parameter “it must be the function’s only parameter”. So you should send the parameters inside the form, using inputs of types “hidden” or “text”, then, from code.gs you can retrieve the input data of the Form object.
Another thing stated in the documentation [1] in the “form” section, is that you need to disable the default submit action with preventFormSubmit function.

Another problem is that the correct way of printing the variables passed to the template are using `<?= ?>` instead of `<? ?>` which works to execute code but not to print variables. [2]

Your “addFile” function is all right. Below is the code i've tested on my environment and I was able to upload an image successfully and print the url in the sheet.

**Index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_center">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form id="myForm">
      Please upload image below.<br /><br />
    <input type="hidden" name="fname" id="fname" value="<?= fName ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="position" id="position" value="<?= position ?>"/>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" accept="image/jpeg,.pdf" />
    <input type="button" value="Submit" class="action" onclick="formData(this.parentNode)" />
    <input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />
  </form>
  <script>
  //Disable the default submit action  using “func1”
   window.onload=func1;
   function func1() {
      document.getElementById('myForm').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
          });  
   }

   function formData(obj){
       google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(closeIt).upload(obj);
   }   

  function closeIt(e){
      console.log(e);
      google.script.host.close();
  };   

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Code.gs (upload function):**

```
function upload(obj) {
  //Retrieve the input data of the Form object.
  var newFileName = obj.fname;
  var rowNum = obj.position;
  var blob = obj.file;

  var upFile = DriveApp.getFolderById('[folderid]').createFile(blob).setName(newFileName);
  var fileUrl = upFile.getUrl();

  var urlCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange(rowNum,5);
  urlCell.setValue('=HYPERLINK("' + fileUrl + '","View image")');

}
```

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication

[2] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates

Comment: Thank you for this explanation! Seems like that was the issue, and I've been able to insert this code into my project and have successfully upload a file and find the function with the URL in the cell. Thanks again!

I am still new to Apps Script and do not have much experience with HTML coding, so the idea of an object and how it transfers between client-side and server-side was a foreign concept to me before now. I did come across the [1] documentation, but missed this information.

Very grateful for the explanation, again, and I'm glad I'm learning more and more. Cheers!

Comment: hi is there a way to do this without the file select, but rather with a blob of an image that was generated via a canvas?

Comment: This [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob) may help you

Comment: I used the above code, after uploading the image, submit button is pressed but it does not go forward or does anything, it just stucks there, kindly can you guide me about it?